# How can I read shortened urls with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nltk, url-shortener

How can I read shortened urls with python?

I have a list of shortened urls and i would like to get the real url or read the content of the page at least

{'urlshortened': 3, 'urlshortened': 3, 'urlshortened': 3,}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the requests library and then use bs4 to get the page content, you should learn more about web **scraping**